# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, uiautomation

I am getting the following **Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:     
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver    
The method get(String) is undefined for the type WebDriver at selOne.New.main(New.java:15)
```

**Code:**

```
package selOne;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class New {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/name/Downloads/selenium-java-3.141.59/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        String baseurl = "http://www.google.com/";
        driver.get(baseurl);
    }
}
```

Comment: problem not solved please provide another solution

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the webdriver outside the main class.

```
package selOne;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class New {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String baseurl;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/name/Downloads/selenium-java-3.141.59/chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        baseurl = "http://www.google.com/";
        driver.get(baseurl);

    }
}
```

Let me know if this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have added the external jars in the ModulePath.

**Solution:**

Remove the external jars from the node "Modulepath". Select the node "Classpath" then add the external jars. Check  selenium jar is imported.

Comment: i added in classpath only. Pleasefind screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The solution of adding the selenium jars in "classpath" and not in "Modulepath"  in project build helps in overcoming the error message.